# Angularjs xeditable - Save without edit

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

I am using angular x-editable to edit html table inline. The problem is I need to give the users option to save whatever data is in the table without putting it in edit mode. If I do that, then my scope value is getting wiped out in onaftersave method.

But if I first put the form in edit mode, and then hit save, everything works fine.

Here is the JSFiddle showing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/0yvhd84o/

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl" style="margin: 50px">
 <form editable-form name="tableform" onaftersave="saveTable()">

     <table class='table table-bordered'>
         <tr style="font-weight: bold">
             <td>Name</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>   
             <td>

                  <span editable-text="user.name" e-form="tableform" onaftersave="saveTable()">
            {{ user.name || 'empty' }}
          </span>
             </td>
         </tr>
     </table>
         <div class="btn-edit">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-show="!tableform.$visible" ng-click="tableform.$show()">
        edit
      </button>
                   <button type="submit" ng-disabled="tableform.$waiting" class="btn btn-primary">save</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-form" ng-show="tableform.$visible">


      <button type="button" ng-disabled="tableform.$waiting" ng-click="tableform.$cancel()" class="btn btn-default">cancel</button>
    </div> 
</form>
    <br><br>
    <div class="row">
        Result is: {{result}}
    </div>
</div>
```

**AngularJS**

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["xeditable"]);

app.run(function(editableOptions) {
  editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
});

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.user = {
    name: 'awesome user',
    status: 2
  };


    $scope.saveTable = function(){

        $scope.result = $scope.user.name ;
    }

    $scope.result = '';

});
```

Is there a way to achieve this, so that users should not have to enter edit mode if they dont have to make any changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out. Here is the solution in case someone else needs it:

You need to add ng-click="tableform.$show()" to save button as well

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="tableform.$waiting" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="tableform.$show()">save</button>
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/9eg11s0o/